# How can I fetch data with useEffect in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make the search bar when the `searchQuery === ""` the user list will be clear and the data will disappear if I clear all the word in input.

Here is my following code:

```
const Invitees = (props) => {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [invitees, setInvitees] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSearchQuery(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/v1/search/users/invite/${searchQuery}`);
    setInvitees(res.data[0]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchQuery === "") {
      setInvitees([]);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="invitees-container">
      <div className="invitees-wrapper">
        <div className="invitees-sortes">
          Sort by: <u>Recommended</u>{" "}
          <svg
            width="12"
            height="6"
            viewBox="0 0 12 6"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <path d="M6 6L0.803848 0L11.1962 0L6 6Z" fill="#A9A9A9" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div className="invitees-search">
          <Button
            className="input invitees--search-icon"
            style={{ color: "white", backgroundColor: "#00B790" }}
            type="submit"
            onClick={handleSubmit}
          >
            <SearchIcon />
          </Button>
          <input
            className="invitees--search_input"
            type="search"
            name="name"
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="Name, Skill, Location"
            aria-label="Search bar"
            pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"
            required
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <Grid
        container
        direction="row"
        justify="flex-start"
        alignItems="stretch"
        spacing={6}
      >
        {invitees.map((user, index) => (
          <Grid item className="invitees-card" key={index}>
            {user.Memberships.length < 1 && <InviteCard user={user} />}
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

How can I achieve that feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add dependencies in `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchQuery === "") {
      setInvitees([]);
    }
  }, [searchQuery ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a condition in handle change

```
 const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target.value === '') {
       setInvitees([])
    }
    setSearchQuery(event.target.value);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   axios
     .get('/api/v1/search/users/invite/${searchQuery}')
     .then((res) => res.data)
     .then((data) => setInvitees(data[0]));
 }, []);
```

Try that?

I think your axios should be indeed in the useEffect.

And you keep the condition you want in it.